# How to understand voltage change between different phases of BLDC?

Tags: inductance, brushless-dc-motor

Actually, it is a question about an application note of BLDC from [here](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/application_note/CD00041736.pdf).
[image]
（on page 30 of that material）

The question is about calculation of potential of M. What I learned from book is that the voltage of inductance is proportional to the speed of current change. So, I do not think it is
a constant value, like HV/3?? Which parts do I misunderstand??

Comment: Your image isn't showing.

Comment: @OlinLathrop，I just uploaded image again. If it is still broken, you can check page 30 of uploaded reference material